# C++ file.close() gives extra time

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

I am reading approximately 230 million floats from a `file` (that takes approx `2GB` of disk space) into a `vector<vector<float>> v`. Then, I create `vector<float*> t` such that `t[i] = (&(v[i][0]))` for all valid `i`. This `t` then goes to input to a function `f`. There are two ways in which I can do this:

```
if(file.is_open()){
    while(...)
    // read floats into v
}
else{
    // something
}
// create t
// start timer
// run function f(t)
// end timer
```

And

```
if(file.is_open()){
    while(...)
    // read floats into v
    file.close() --- **this wasn't present earlier** 
}
else{
    // something
}
// create t
// start timer
// run function f(t)
// end timer
```

The first approach takes approx 37 sec, while the second approach takes approx 49 sec.

My question is: why is that the case? I'm timing the code only when it is executing the function `f`, then why am I getting such a significant difference?

---

**EDIT**

The code goes as:

```
int n = 114141986; // number of data points
int d = 2;
vector<float> temp;
for(int i=0; i<d; i++)
    temp.push_back(0);
vector<vector<float>> data(n, temp);
string path = "cleanedData/"+to_string(d)+"d1.txt";
ifstream file(path.c_str());
if(file.is_open()){
    int j = 0;
    string line;
    while(getline(file, line)){
        istringstream in(line);
        for(int i=0; i<d; i++){
            in>>data[j][i];
        }
        j++;
    }
    file.close();
}
else{
    cout<<"Unable to open file "<<path<<endl;
    exit(1);
}
vector<float*> vec(n);
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    vec[i] = (&(data[i][0]));
}
cout<<"Done"<<endl;
// to check time taken to build the tree
time_t start, end; 
time(&start); 
cout<<"Building tree..."<<endl;
node *root = buildTree(vec);
time(&end);
```

`buildTree` is a huge function, and is accompanied by many more functions. So don't think it'd be a good idea to post that.

Comment: I think we'll need to see a wee bit more code to get a good idea of what's going on here.

Comment: @AdrianMole sure. Give me a min

Comment: was the test compiled with optimization enabled? also i guarantee you that performance hit is negligible compared to reading a line and then re-parsing values out of it with `istringstream`. Just pull the values out directly and see how fast that is. Also `vector<array<float, 2>>` would likely be better if you don't need jagged arrays

Comment: @CruzJean Umm I don't know how to do that (enable optimization). Also, how can I "pull the values out directly"? C++ will be reading the file in strings and I'll need floats/ Isn't `istringstream` the way to do that? If not, can you please suggest me a possibly faster alternative?

Comment: @AnkitKumar Well you can just do `file >> some_float_variable`. On each row try to read one float value (to a temp variable) - if that succeeds, add a row (and that value) and continue reading the other `d-1` floats in that row from the file

Comment: @CruzJean thanks, it works perfectly. I didn't know we can use the file directly like this. It doesn't improve anything though. The time is still 49 +- 1 or 2 seconds

Comment: @AnkitKumar ya, the `>>` thing is any `istream` (`ifstream`, `istringstream`, `cin`, etc.). as for speed, did you try changing the type to `vector<array<float, 2>>`? this would avoid one dynamic allocation per row and would increase cache cohesion. if you're using gcc/g++/clang/clang++ you enable optimization with the `-O3` option. msvc uses `/O2`

Comment: @CruzJean I can't do that. It'll remove the "generality" of my code

Comment: @AnkitKumar if d is a constant it would not, otherwise you should try re-writing this as a flattened 1-D array

Comment: @CruzJean `d` can vary significantly from 2 to inf (theoretically) depending upon what file the user wants to process. That's not the option I have. I can't write this as a 1-D array. You see each of those d-length tuples represent data for one node. Would like to work with that straightway. But I don't think its related to `file.close()` in any manner anyway

Comment: @AnkitKumar if you don't know what a flattened array is: instead of having `vector<vector<T>>` of sizes `n` and `m` you just use `vector<T>` of size `n*m` and apply index logic to get items *as if* it were a 2D array (make a helper function for this or make a class to represent it)

Comment: @CruzJean I'll sort this `n*d` vec at a later stage. Flattening it will screw up everything. But again, it doesn't have anything to do with my problem. The code for both the situations is EXACTLY same, except one line. I don't get it why's that giving me those extra 12 seconds

Comment: Enable your compilers optimizations and get a nice speed boost.

Comment: @JesperJuhl yes, I"ll do that. Thank you!

Comment: @AnkitKumar Are there any IO operations (file read/write, cin/cout etc.) inside buildTree(vec) ?

Comment: @foolo No. None at all. The above code shown for `file` is the only file read operation I do. There are no file write operations whatsoever. And yes, I'm only printing before and after `buildTree`. None in this one or any other functions.